# Scaling Ipad App up to Larger Ipad Screen Size

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, scaling

How can I scale up an iPad app that I am working on that works fine on the 9.7" model but does not zoom-in/scale when running simulation for iPad Pro (12.9-inch). Basically looks something like this when running it on the simulator for the 12.9" model:

I've tried to mess with the launch screen and Launch Image Source from reading some other posts but no luck. Any ideas ? 
[image]

Comment: How are you laying out your content?  Are you using constraints?  What constraints have you used?  It looks like you have either used a fixed size or haven't otherwise constrained your content to the superview edges.

Comment: I have not used constraints because the previous development done to the app was set up like that. I am still getting the hang of iOS development, how would I go about just allowing the app to "zoom-in" without native resolution on a bigger display?

Comment: You need to use constraints so that your layout adapts to the screen size.